# c++, problems with switch operator

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

Now I am looking through some c++ test, and here I found such code:

```
int main()
{

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0: cout<<"ZERO";
        case 1: cout<<"ONE"; continue;
        case 2: cout<<"TWO"; break;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
ZEROONEONETWO
```

I debugged and found that case 0 and case 1 executed when i = 0, why it happened?

Comment: If you put `break;` after the cout, it won't go to the next case.

Comment: FYI, `switch` is a statement, not an operator.

Comment: In C & C++, cases fall through in the absence of a break.

Comment: Please highlight your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit `case 0:` it will fall through to `case 1:` since there is no statement to prevent it from doing so such as a `break` or `continue`.

Comment: Buy why it will fall through to case1:, if i!=1 ?

Comment: @VitaliK Because that's how the language is designed. So you can write code like `case 0: case 1: case 2: cout << "print this if i is either 0, 1, or 2"; break;`

Comment: @VitaliK Each `case` will only give you an entry point once you start executing you will keep going until you hit a `break` in this example since you have a `loop` you can also use `continue` to break out. This behavior is called `fall through` this reference may help http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/53-switch-statements/.

Comment: @Shafik YaghmourOk, thx, I understood. It`s just a label for entry. I've just never used labels like goto, that is why I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

break statement is  missing at case 0

Answer (score 1):

`switch` just jumps to the matching `case` label. After you've done that, further `case` labels are ignored. Note also that there is no implicit `break` - if you leave it out, subsequent code is executed in sequence.

So,

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)             // statements (1,2,3)
{
    switch(i)                       // statement 4
    {
    case 0: cout<<"ZERO";           // statement 5
    case 1: cout<<"ONE"; continue;  // statements 6; 7
    case 2: cout<<"TWO"; break;     // statements 8; 9
    }
    cout<<endl;                     // statement 10
}
```

unwinds to

```
i = 0;                    // statement 1
// begin first iteration with i=0
if (i<3) => true          // statement 2
switch (i) => goto case 0 // statement 4
case 0: cout<<"ZERO"      // statement 5
        cout<<"ONE";      // statement 6
        continue;         // statement 7
        => jump to next iteration of loop
i++;                      // statement 3
if (i<3) => true          // statement 2
// second iteration, i=1
switch (i) => goto case 1 // statement 4
case 1: cout<<"ONE";      // statement 6
        continue;         // statement 7
        => jump to next iteration of loop
i++;                      // statement 3
if (i<3) => true          // statement 2
// second iteration, i=2
switch (i) => goto case 2 // statement 4
case 2: cout<<"TWO";      // statement 8
        break;            // statement 9
        => jump to end of switch
cout << endl;             // statement 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding of the switch statement is a common one, and it derives from the fact that switch statements are often introduced as if they where more-convenient-to-type if-then-else statements.

They are not!

Think of them like a cascade of instruction. The unit of measurement for its height is the `instruction`.

You decide the height, that is, the instructions between the first `case` match and the most near subsequent `break`.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You need a break statement otherwise you will get "fall through"

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the break statment

```
switch(i){
    case 0:
        {
            //do something
            break;
        }
    case 1:
        {
            //do something
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            //do something
            break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

because every case needs a break statement. If the case true then it will execute until it found a break statement or switch braces end.

your desired code

```
int main()
{

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0: cout<<"ZERO"; break;
        case 1: cout<<"ONE"; continue;
        case 2: cout<<"TWO"; break;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `continue` for `case 1`?